# Firebase datetime convert error on python

Tags: python, firebase, datetime

Can someone explain how i can calculate the time in `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f"` from my Firebase timestamp? I am receiving an error

> signed integer is greater than maximum

when i do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
def formatdatetime(sfd):
  ts = datetime(sfd)
  print(datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f", ts))

formatdatetime(1521508504583)
```

I'm guessing that I'm not taking in the milliseconds correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) or [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) to parse the timestamp.

Second, I believe the timestamp you shared is in milliseconds rather than seconds, so you should divide it by `1000`.

Example:

```
>>> dt = 1521508504583

>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 18, 15, 4)

>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 20, 1, 15, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input integer is too big. 
    OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
[datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
Raise OverflowError instead of ValueError if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C gmtime() function.
```